# Why is creating this UDF so much faster in PySpark than in Scala Spark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have the Python script:

```
import time

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

from urllib.parse import urlsplit, unquote


def extractPath(host, url):
    if host in url:
        return urlsplit(url).path
    else:
        return '-'

startCreateUdfs = time.time()
getPathUdf = udf(extractPath, StringType())
endCreateUdfs = time.time()

print("Python udf creation time: {}".format(endCreateUdfs - startCreateUdfs))
```

and the Scala script:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.net.URL

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

object UdfTimes extends App{

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val extractPath: (String, String) => String = (host, url) => {
    if (url.contains(host))
      new URL(url).getPath
    else
      "-"
  }
  val unquote: String => String = str => URLDecoder.decode(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())

  val startTimeUdf = System.nanoTime()
  val getPathUdf = udf(extractPath)
  val endTimeUdf = System.nanoTime()

  println("Scala udf registering time: " + (endTimeUdf - startTimeUdf) / math.pow(10, 9))
}
```

Which I have written to do the same thing. The udf creation is instant in Python (from command line):

```
Python udf creation time: 2.0503997802734375e-05
```

but in Scala, it takes almost a second (sbt command line):

```
udf registering time: 0.768687091
```

What is the reason for this big difference?

Comment: As a side note, there are built ins for what you want to do, and for performance issues you should then avoid creating udf :)

Comment: I havent spent time in researching this. But, the first thing that comes to me is that Scripting languages are typically quick and dirty and are not complied.

Comment: Are you using the sbt command line in paste mode? There is a significant overhead if you do it "instruction-by-instruction", whichever code you're running.